# Unable to mount FS as a non root user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I have a nginx image that runs as non root (user is nginx UID 101 GID 101 )in kubernetes. This image also has `gcsfuse` installed in it.

As the image runs with `nginx` user, I would like this user to mount a GCS bucket. When I try this, it fails

```sh
nginx@clamav-mirror-frontend-f5f6f8f8-9hlgs:/$ id
uid=101(nginx) gid=101(nginx) groups=101(nginx)

nginx@clamav-mirror-frontend-f5f6f8f8-9hlgs:/$ gcsfuse test-clamav-mirror /data
2021/12/08 20:09:42.144896 Start gcsfuse/0.38.0 (Go version go1.17.3) for app "" using mount point: /data
2021/12/08 20:09:42.261297 Opening GCS connection...
2021/12/08 20:09:42.588103 Mounting file system "test-clamav-mirror"...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running /bin/fusermount: exit status 1
```

I went through this [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#access-permissions) and tried the following but the same result

```sh
nginx@clamav-mirror-frontend-f5f6f8f8-9hlgs:/$ gcsfuse -o rw,_netdev,allow_other,uid=101,gid=101 test-clamav-mirror /data
2021/12/08 20:10:22.460757 Start gcsfuse/0.38.0 (Go version go1.17.3) for app "" using mount point: /data
2021/12/08 20:10:22.562672 Opening GCS connection...
2021/12/08 20:10:22.959742 Mounting file system "test-clamav-mirror"...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running /bin/fusermount: exit status 1
```

Is this even possible or am I missing some config ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

The path that I want to mount my bucket on `/data` needed to be owned by `ngnix` user. It was previously owned by `root`. The moment I gave ownership to `nginx` it now successfully mounts.